# How to add custom function ot User.php in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I added the following custom function to `User.php`:

```
public function isUpgraded() {
    return true;
}
```

and the following in my `Foreground.skin.php` which is my skin/theme for the wiki to simply access the value that the function returns:

```
$isUpgraded= $wgUser->isUpgraded();
```

but I get the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method User::isUpgraded() in /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/skins/foreground/Foreground.skin.php:106 Stack trace: #0 /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(251): foregroundTemplate->execute() #1 /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/includes/OutputPage.php(2388): SkinTemplate->outputPage() #2 /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/includes/exception/MWExceptionRenderer.php(135): OutputPage->output() #3 /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/includes/exception/MWExceptionRenderer.php(54): MWExceptionRenderer::reportHTML(Object(Error)) #4 /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/includes/exception/MWExceptionHandler.php(75): MWExceptionRenderer::output(Object(Error), 2) #5 /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/includes/exception/MWExceptionHandler.php(149): MWExceptionHandler::report(Object(Error)) #6 /home/siteX/public_html/dev. in /home/siteX/public_html/siteX.com/wiki/skins/foreground/Foreground.skin.php on line 106
```

Do I need to register the custom function in some other file in order for it to work? It might be worth mentioning that the code worked in `MediaWiki 1.23` but I recently updated to `1.31` and can't get the following piece of code to work.

Comment: Modifying core files is very discouraged; can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? Maybe we can figure out a better way, that won't break on upgrades.

Comment: Sounds like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yeah it would probably be more clever to use a usergroup and built in functions.